# Not playing sounds from stream_url ing SoundCloud API

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I can display the songs in the table view but i cant play it.

here's my code when get tracks button is tapped

```
- (IBAction) getTracks:(id) sender
{

    SCRequestResponseHandler handler;
    handler = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                             JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:0
                                             error:&jsonError];
        if (!jsonError && [jsonResponse isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            SCTTrackListViewController *trackListVC;
            trackListVC = [[SCTTrackListViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"SCTTrackListViewController"
                           bundle:nil];
            trackListVC.tracks = (NSArray *)jsonResponse;
            NSLog(@"json %@",(NSArray *)jsonResponse);
            [self presentViewController:trackListVC
                               animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    };



    NSString *resourceURL = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/54237635/tracks.json?client_id=8a58d84d48322f5661cf14a3d80e005d";


    [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                  onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:resourceURL]
             usingParameters:nil
                 withAccount:nil
      sendingProgressHandler:nil
             responseHandler:handler];
}
```

here's my code in didselect in tableview :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *track = [self.tracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *streamURL = [track objectForKey:@"stream_url"];


    [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                  onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:streamURL]
             usingParameters:nil
                 withAccount:nil
      sendingProgressHandler:nil
             responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                 NSError *playerError;
                 player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&playerError];
                 [player prepareToPlay];
                 [player play];
             }];

    NSLog(@"streamURL %@", [track objectForKey:@"stream_url"]);
}
```

Comment: What have you learned about the handling of the response from using the debugger? Please share that info.

Comment: what do you mean? do you know what's the problem with the code?

Comment: No, I'm asking you to share more details about what you've found during debugging. Does the response handler fire, for instance? What are the values of its arguments? and so on

Comment: Hey carl i already figured it out check the code now. BTW thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the OP:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
{

NSDictionary *track = [self.tracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *streamURL = [track objectForKey:@"stream_url"];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@", streamURL,CLIENT_ID];//Your client ID


[SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
              onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
         usingParameters:nil
             withAccount:nil
  sendingProgressHandler:nil
         responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
             NSError *playerError;

             NSLog(@"data:%@",data);
             player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&playerError];
             [player prepareToPlay];
             [player play];
         }];
}
```